# Bot launches fine, but the commands do not work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

This is probably a duplicate question or a newbie Python error, but I just can’t find the right terms to search for my answer.

My bot launches fine, and it even runs the print function on `on_ready`! However, when I try using the commands there aren't any responses. It worked fine before I added the `class GlobalBanningSystem(commands.Cog):`, so I dont know!

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")

class GlobalBanningSystem(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.has_role("966695793555804232") # Staff Role ID
    async def gban(self, ctx, member: discord.User):
        channel = self.bot.get_channel("966681817094697020") # Logs Channel ID
        auth = ctx.author

        await ctx.send("Ban Issue successfuly opened. Now, please type the ban reason!")
        reason = await self.bot.wait_for('message', timeout = 600)

        embed = discord.Embed(title = f"Global Banned {member.name}", colour = 0xFF0000)
        embed.add_field(name = "Reason:", value = reason.content, inline = False)
        embed.add_field(name = "User ID:", value = f"`{member.id}`",)
        embed.add_field(name = "Staff Member:", value = f"{auth.name}")
        embed.set_thumbnail(url = member.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        await ctx.send(f"**{member.name}** has been globbaly banned!")
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            await guild.ban(member)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Global Banning System is online!")

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Bot's Response Latency: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms")

client.run("token:>")
```

I was trying a ban command that would ban the user from:

1. all the servers that the user was in
2. all the servers that the bot was in

Comment: Note: IDs must be integers. The `has_role` check has no effect, and `channel` will be `None`.

Comment: @Eric Jin oh so do I just add int() before them? I thought about that but i also thought that it would act as a string, the "int(123)" would have been marked as an string xD

Comment: @Bella Simply integer literals, such as `has_permissions(12345)` would suffice.

Comment: @Eric Jin ohhh I see!

Comment: Another minor thing, you probably want to wrap the ban in try/except for `discord.errors.Forbidden`, because if you don't have permission in one guild it will completely destroy the command for all the others.

Comment: @Eric Jin that's actually really helpful. Could you give me an example of how exactly to use that?

Comment: `try:`, then do things, then `except discord.errors.Forbidden`, then you can do something (eg warn that a ban failed in a guild), or just ignore it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register the cog with your bot:

```
client.add_cog(GlobalBanningSystem(client))
```

Comment: By the way, where would I add this?

Comment: in your main bot file